# How to enable logging for subprocesses

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, multiprocessing

Here is a simple script:

```
import logging
import multiprocessing
    
def run(i):
    logging.info(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)

    logging.info('Sequential:')
    for i in range(3):
        run(i)

    logging.info('Parallel:')
    for i in range(3):
        pool.apply_async(run, [i])

    logging.info('Done')
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The output is as follows:

```
INFO:root:Sequential:
INFO:root:0
INFO:root:1
INFO:root:2
INFO:root:Parallel:
INFO:root:Done
```

Why subprocesses doesn't output anything? How to fix it?

There are a lot of [complicated tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes). Is there a simpler way to log to stdout/stderr?

It seems that [multiprocessing_logging](https://github.com/jruere/multiprocessing-logging) module doesn't work on Windows. So I can't use it.

Comment: This seems to be platform-dependent. It works fine on Linux.

Comment: Works fine on Mac too. Could you please try running it again, and perhaps add a regular print statement to the 'run' function? I find it surprising that it doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've spent hours to make it work. After your comments I've found a simple solution. The problem is that a logger should be configured for each process.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine even without `multiprocessing_logging` module. The logger should be configured for each subprocess. Please see the first line added to `run()`. Here is a full code:

```
import logging
import multiprocessing

def run(i):
    logging.basicConfig(format=logging.BASIC_FORMAT, level=logging.INFO)
    logging.info(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)

    logging.info('Sequential:')
    for i in range(3):
        run(i)

    logging.info('Parallel:')
    for i in range(3):
        pool.apply_async(run, [i])

    logging.info('Done')
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I guess that `multiprocessing_logging` should be used anyway to counter problems caused by a concurent access to stdout/stderr.